# How to create undirected graph out of adjancency matrix?

Tags: c++, matrix

Hello everywhere there is an explanation by drawings hot to create graph out of adj. matrix. However, i need simple pseudo code or algorithym for that .... I know how to draw it out of adj. matrix and dont know why nobody no where explains how to actually put it in code. I dont mean actual code but at least algorithm ... Many say .. 1 is if there is an edge i know that.. I have created the adj. matrix and dont know how to transfer it to graph. My vertices dont have names they are just indexes of the matrix. for example 1-9 are the "names of my matrix"

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
2 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
4 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
5 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
6 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
7 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
8 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
9 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

that was originaly a maze ... have to mark row1 col4 as start and row7 col8 end ...

Nobody ever told me how to implement graph out of matrix (without pen) :Pp

thanks

Comment: An adjacency matrix _is_ a way of representing a graph. Do you mean you want to convert to another representation? And if so, how would you like to represent the graph?

Answer (score 1):

**Nature of symmetry**

Adjancency matrix is a representation of a graph. For undirected graph, its matrix is symmetrical. For instance, if there is an edge from `vertex i` to `vertex j`, there must also be an edge from `vertex j` to `vertex i`. That is the same edge actually.

```
* 
  * 
    *     A'
  A   * 
        *
          *
```

**Algorithm**

Noticing this nature, you can implement your algorithm as simple as:

```
void drawGraph(vertices[nRows][nCols])
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nRows; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = i; j < nCols; ++j)
        {
            drawLine(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm I guess I didnt ask the quesion right .. I have that part... That one just print the adj matrix.... I want to convert the adj matrix to graph ... I have it set now I want to create a graph from the matrix i posted. I have an idea but not sure... something like: node n1 = adjMatrix[0][0]

Comment: I want to know how to create vertices out of that matrix and how to transfer edges from the matrix to them ?

Comment: @user478984: adjMatrix[i][j] is not the vertex itself, it represents how many edges connecting vertices i and j. i and j are vertices. Are you asking DRAWING the graph out of the matrix of something else?

Comment: i want to convert adj matrix to graph and then to proceed with DFS ... Everything is clear for me just dont know how to create the graph ... out of my adj . matrix. It has to work not just for that adj matrix but for any as input .... heh ..

Comment: @user478984: The adjacency matrix _is_ a representation of the graph. You can do DFS on it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a graph from an adjacency matrix representation to a node-based representation like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int adjmatrix[9][9] = {
  {0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0},
  {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0},
  {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
  {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1},
  {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
  {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0}
};

struct Node {
  vector<Node*> neighbours;
  /* optional additional node information */
};

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  /* initialize nodes */
  vector<Node> nodes(9);

  /* add pointers to neighbouring nodes */
  int i,j;
  for (i=0;i<9;++i) {
    for (j=0;j<9;++j) {
      if (adjmatrix[i][j]==0) continue;
      nodes[i].neighbours.push_back(&nodes[j]);
    }
  }

  /* print number of neighbours */
  for (i=0;i<9;++i) {
    cout << "Node " << i
         << " has " << nodes[i].neighbours.size() <<" outbound edges." << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here, the graph is represented as an array of nodes with pointers to reachable neighbouring nodes. After setting up the nodes and their neighbour pointers you use this data structure to perform the graph algorithms you want, in this (trivial) example print out the number of outbound directed edges each node has.